# Linux command to insert multiple lines into xml file

Tags: linux, shell, awk, sed

Linux command to insert multiple lines into xml file before match/pattern.  Tried with the following command :

```
#finding pattern:
toOccurance=`grep -n "\<copy file=\"${appletResource}\/images\/CCMsplash.gif\" toFile=\"${appletbuild}\/splash.gif\" \/>" abc.xml | awk -F: '{print $1}'`

toOccurance=$(($toOccurance -1 ))

sed -i "$toOccurance /a \<copy todir=\"${controlbuild\}\" flatten=\"true\">\n
                \<fileset dir=\"${appletResource}\">\n
                        \<include name=\"crop.properties\"\/>\n
                        \<include name=\"vvm.xml\"\/>\n
                        \<exclude name=\"images\/\*splash.gif\"\/> 
                <\/fileset>
        <\/copy>" abc.xml
```

No error is shown but the command doesn't work. Any pointers on how to fix it ?

Comment: This might help: [How to debug a bash script?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/155551/74329)

Comment: Use an XML parser to parse XML. Show some of your XML and describe what you want to do.

Comment: Next time your car breaks down, take it to the garage and just tell the mechanic `the car doesn't work. Any pointers on how to fix it ?` and see how he reacts. You MIGHT want to provide more info in your question - sample input, expected output, actual output, other symptoms, error messages, etc.

Comment: Using `grep` to find the line number you want to change so you can pass it to `sed` is a massive antipattern. `sed` is quite capable of finding a line which matches a regular expression all by itself.

Comment: @tripleee You mean "using grep to pipe to awk to use the result with sed" ;)

Answer (score 0):

Your sed "a" command is wrong. Change:

```
sed -i "$toOccurance /a blah blah blah....
```

to

```
sed -i "${toOccurance}a blah blah blah....
```

but @tripleee is right, you could just as well use `sed` to find the lines number rather than all the business at the top.  *But one working script is worth two "it would be better this way" scripts, I guess*.

Answer (score -1):

## Update before a specified match/pattern in xml file.....

## !/bin/sh

function updateXML () {
    abcFilePath=abc.xml
    echo "Updating file $abcFilePath"

```
if [ -f $abcFilePath ];
then
    echo "File $abcFilePath exists"
else
    echo "File $abcFilePath does not exists"

dos2unix $abcFilePath
fi

    toOccurance=`grep -n '\<copy file=\"${appletResource}\/images\/CCMsplash.gif\" toFile=\"${appletbuild}\/splash.gif\" \/>' $abcFilePath | awk -F: '{print $1}'`

toOccurance=$(($toOccurance - 1 ))

echo "toOccurance =  $toOccurance"
```

sed -i "${toOccurance}a \n\\n\\n\\n\n</fileset>\n</copy>" $abcFilePath

echo "Updated file "

}

updateXML